# Loop through raster names in two folders, perform Con (Spatial Analyst tool) if the dates match

Tags: arcpy, raster, spatial-analyst, conditional

I cannot perform the Con tool over all the raster images with same date in two folders.
This is the script I have worked upon so far.

```py
import arcpy, os
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set the current workspace 
location_a = "D:/datasets/regression_interpolation_rasters/airtemp_snowmask_regression_rasters"
location_b = "D:/datasets/regression_interpolation_rasters/regression_rasters"
location = "D:/datasets/regression_interpolation_rasters/snowmask_rasters"

# get the names of rasters 
arcpy.env.workspace = location_a
snow_raster = arcpy.ListRasters("", "TIF")
#print(type(snow_raster))
for snow_ras in snow_raster:
    snow = Raster(snow_ras)
    #print(type(snow))
    snow_name = snow_ras.split("_")
    snow_values = snow_name[2]
    #print(snow_values)

# get the names of rasters 
arcpy.env.workspace = location_b
airtemp_raster = arcpy.ListRasters("", "TIF")
#print(airtemp_raster)
for airtemp_ras in airtemp_raster:
    airtemp = Raster(airtemp_ras)
    airtemp_name = airtemp_ras.split("_")
    airtemp_values = airtemp_name[0]
    #print(airtemp_values)

    if airtemp_values == snow_values:
        output_raster = Con(snow_raster==1, 0, airtemp_raster)  
        output = os.path.join(location,airtemp_ras.split("_")[0] +'_airtemp'+ '.tif')
        output_raster.save(output)
            #print("yes")
    else:
        print("action cannot take place")
```

All it is showing the else statement even though the dates match.The placement of the dates vary but the format of dates are similar.These are the images in location_b

[image]

These are the images in location_a

[image]

I have revised my code to:

```py
import arcpy, os
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set the current workspace
location_a = "D:/datasets/regression_interpolation_rasters/airtemp_snowmask_regression_rasters"
location_b = "D:/datasets/regression_interpolation_rasters/interpolation_rasters_for_testing"
location = "D:/datasets/regression_interpolation_rasters/snowmask_rasters"

# get the names of rasters
snow_raster_dict = dict()
arcpy.env.workspace = location_a
snow_raster_list = arcpy.ListRasters("", "TIF")
#print(type(snow_raster))

for snow_name in snow_raster_list:
    snow_raster = Raster(snow_name)
    #print(type(snow))
    snow_name_parts = snow_name.split("_")
    snow_date = snow_name_parts[2]
    snow_raster_dict[snow_date] = snow_raster
    #print(snow_values) ##22 line##
    
# get the names of rasters ##14 line##
arcpy.env.workspace = location_b
airtemp_raster_list = arcpy.ListRasters("", "TIF")
#print(airtemp_raster)

for airtemp_name in airtemp_raster_list:
    airtemp_raster = Raster(airtemp_name)
    airtemp_name_parts = airtemp_name.split("_")
    airtemp_date = airtemp_name_parts[0]
    #print(airtemp_values)
    try:
        snow_date == airtemp_date
        output_raster = Con(snow_raster==1, 0, airtemp_raster)  
        output = os.path.join(location,airtemp_name.split("_")[0] +'_airtemp'+ '.tif')
        output_raster.save(output)
            #print("yes")
    except KeyError:
        print(f"no snow raster found for {airtemp_date}")
```

After editing the code images whose dates match are being stored but somehow all the images have the same pixel value of 1 replaced by 0 which is incorrect.
What I am trying to achieve is producing an image where the pixel values of 1 are converted to 0 and the pixel values of 0 are replaced with the pixel values of another image using the images with the same dates.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: One of the single most powerful features of Python is its native support for dictionaries. Walking a list to do comparisons is just asking for list offset trouble.  I suggest you learn to use dictionary lookups instead.

Answer (score 0):

After you spit your file names and extract the dates you have your list indices mixed up.

`snow_values = snow_name[2]` for location_A should be `snow_values = snow_name[0]`

and

`snow_values = snow_name[0]` for locationBB should be `snow_values = snow_name[2]`

Given your comment then:
airtemp_raster is a list of rasters in a workspace and not an individual raster layer...

```
`output_raster = Con(snow_raster==1, 0, airtemp_raster)`
```

should be

```
output_raster = Con(snow_raster==1, 0, airtemp)
```

Comment: I corrected the labeling of the raster images in the screenshot. The screenshot labelling was wrong, which has been corrected now.

Comment: I have altered my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through both folders is pretty inefficient. I would propose the following logic (which only uses a single loop):

1. For each image in folder A, extract the date into a variable
2. Construct the path to the corresponding image in folder B based on the date (regardless of whether it actually exists)
3. Check whether the constructed path exists with `os.path.exists()` or `arcpy.Exists()`
4. If step 3 returns `True`, then run your `Con()`

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to gather the code with some additional help.Here is the code.

```py
import arcpy, os
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env

# Set the current workspace
location_a = "D:/datasets/planetscope/binary_snow_images_converted"
location_b = "D:/datasets/regression_interpolation_rasters/linear_regression_interpolation_rasters_without_snowmask"
location = "D:/datasets/regression_interpolation_rasters/regression_rasters_after_snowmask"
arcpy.env.extent = "D:/datasets/DEM ALTA_VALTELLINA LOMBARDY REGION/clip_dtm.tif"
arcpy.env.snapRaster = "D:/datasets/DEM ALTA_VALTELLINA LOMBARDY REGION/clip_dtm.tif"
arcpy.env.cellSize = "D:/datasets/regression_interpolation_rasters/linear_regression_interpolation_rasters_without_snowmask/2017-10-01_airtemp.tif"

# get the names of rasters
snow_raster_dict = dict()
all_snow_rasters = []
arcpy.env.workspace = location_a
snow_raster_list = arcpy.ListRasters("", "TIF")


for snow_name in snow_raster_list:
    snow_raster = Raster(snow_name)
    snow_name_parts = snow_name.split("_")
    snow_date = snow_name_parts[2]
    snow_raster_dict[snow_date] = snow_raster
    
    # get the names of rasters ##26 line##
arcpy.env.workspace = location_b
airtemp_raster_list = arcpy.ListRasters("", "TIF")


for airtemp_name in airtemp_raster_list:
    airtemp_raster = Raster(airtemp_name)
    airtemp_name_parts = airtemp_name.split("_")
    airtemp_date = airtemp_name_parts[0]
    try:
        snow_raster = snow_raster_dict[airtemp_date]
        output_raster = Con(snow_raster==1, 0, airtemp_raster)  
        output = os.path.join(location,airtemp_name.split("_")[0] +'_airtemp'+ '.tif')
        output_raster.save(output)
    except KeyError:
        print(f"no snow raster found for {airtemp_date}")
```